# Need help adding a loading indicator to a searchbar that subscribes to a Rxjs subject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have a searchbar field which I use a service to run my search function from like so:

```
// signup.ts

ngOnInit() {
  this.filteredOptions$ = this.searchService.search(this.searchTerm$);
}
```

Where search term is a Subject:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Business Name" aria-label="Number" matInput (keyup)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto">
```

I want to show a loading indicator when the search function starts and when it finished but the problem is that is a service (using injectable). Here is my search function:

```
// searchservice.ts
  public search(terms: Observable<string>): Observable<ABN> {
    return terms.pipe(
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term)),
    );
  }
```

I then subscribe to this on my template. How can I keep it in a seperate file as a service but still update a local variable (isLoading) on the component?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a loading variable to your component, then pipe your source and destination observables in your component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.filteredOptions$ = this.searchService.search(
      this.searchTerm$.pipe(tap(() => this.loading = true)
  ).pipe(finalize(() => this.loading = false));
}
```

That keeps the concern of the loading flag in the component, where I would agree it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a getter in your variable

```
get isLoading() {
  return this.myService.isLoading;
}
```

And in your service

```
  public search(terms: Observable<string>): Observable<ABN> {
    this.isLoading = true;
    return terms.pipe(
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term)),
      finalize(() => this.isLoading = false)
    );
  }
```